# Rails routes with specific character

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rails-routing

I have bellow url request type, that contain `#` character

```
http://localhost:3000#user-name
```

I want to match it to HomeController#show_user, how to write the routes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Uniform Resource Locators (URL)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1738)

> The character "#" is unsafe and should always be encoded because it is
> used in World Wide Web and in other systems to delimit a URL from a
> fragment/anchor identifier that might follow it.

You can't use `#` symbol in your url because it's a reserved character.

You might have seen the usage of symbol like this

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=hello+world#brs
```

But this symbol used here as fragment delimeter.

Comment: @Tiktac, don't forget to accept the answer!

Comment: This doesn't really tell the whole story. You can use fragments to link to a certain element on the page but they are transparent to the server. So even if you could declare that route it could never be reached.